# Point domain to Amazon EC2 Server

Tags: domains, dns, amazon-ec2

I just got a domain from a rather suspicious registrar and I want to point that domain to an EC2 instance from Amazon AWS. I already have an elastic IP ready and just need to point the domain to it.

However my registrar asks me for my nameservers, (ns1.somedomain.com, etc), which I don't have, since Amazon is not your typical webhost. I've read on the amazon forums that you only need to create an A record, which I did, but my registrar forces me to put some values in the ns1 and ns2 fields, so am I doing something wrong? I'm not very familiar with DNS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While many domain name registrars also provide basic [DNS hosting services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_hosting_service) for domains registered through them, it looks like your registrar may be one of the few that don't.  In that case, you basically have two or three options:

1. Use a third-party DNS provider.  There are way too many of those around to list here, but just searching Google for "DNS hosting" will turn up plenty of options.
2. Use Amazon's own [Route 53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/) service, which is presumably better integrated with their other services than an external DNS service would be.
3. Run your own DNS servers as EC2 instances with elastic IPs.  I wouldn't recommend this, since it's complicated and probably gains you nothing over going with Route 53 or an external DNS provider, but I'll list it here for completeness, since it should work in principle.